# "ERROR Error: Argument 2 `isExtractable` must be a function." when uploading files with Apollo Angular

Tags: angular, file-upload, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

According to https://apollo-angular.com/docs/data/network#file-upload, in order to upload files with Apollo Angular you have to add `context: {useMultipart: true}` to the graphQL query, and the `extractFiles` function to the httpLink creation.

However, I keep getting this error. It seems that the default `isExtractableFile` function is not used, and I have no idea why that is.

Here's my `graphql.module.ts`:

```
const uri = environment.graphQLUrl; // <-- add the URL of the GraphQL server here
export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink): ApolloClientOptions<any> {
  return {
    link: httpLink.create({uri, useMultipart: true, extractFiles}),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  };
}

@NgModule({
  exports: [ApolloModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
      useFactory: createApollo,
      deps: [HttpLink],
    },
  ],
})
export class GraphQLModule {}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `extractFiles` function example found in the linked Angular doc to see if there's any discrepancy between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the solution from an open issue on [angular-apollo](https://github.com/kamilkisiela/apollo-angular/issues/1804) repo.

```
import extractFiles from 'extract-files/extractFiles.mjs';
import isExtractableFile from 'extract-files/isExtractableFile.mjs';

httpLink.create({
  ...
  extractFiles: (body) => extractFiles(body, isExtractableFile),
});
```

Comment: This solved the problem!
I'm using 

`{
 "@apollo/client": "3.5.9",
 "apollo-angular": "3.0.1",
 "extract-files": "^13.0.0",
}`